# how to import and install a UEC image on Openstack?

Tags: boot, cloud, openstack, uec, qcow2

Getting started with Openstack here. I've successfully imported and launched instances with a cirros image per the Openstack Installation Guide, but when I import UEC images, like this one [here](http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/trusty/release/ubuntu-14.04-server-cloudimg-amd64.tar.gz) and then attempt to launch instances from it, the instance console reports:

> Booting from Hard Disk...
>   Boot failed: not a bootable disk
>
> No bootable device.

When importing the UEC image, I've tried specifying both RAW and QCOW2 formats to Openstack, but get the same error.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you untar the file first?
I have used the following UEC image many times:

http://uec-images.ubuntu.com/precise/current/precise-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk1.img

Set the image format to QCOW2.

Comment: thanks, I will try using the .img file directly to try to narrow down the problem, but based on the documentation here: http://docs.openstack.org/image-guide/content/ch_introduction.html it seems like a UEC tarball should be directly supported.

Comment: Thanks, using the *-disk1.img works (I wonder what the .img file in the tarball is for?), but now I seem unable to login to the instance with the SSH key pair I told openstack to associate with the instance. Where is the documentation for these images?

Comment: Start looking from here: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud Make sure you log in as the 'ubuntu' user - should work fine with your openstack keypair.